# Enumerate URL Scheme form powershell

Tags: powershell, url, registry

Hey im trying to enumerate URL schemes in the registry but unfortunetly this is  bit harder than i thought

So first of all

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
$REGPATH = "HKCR:\"
Get-ChildItem "$REGPATH" 



    Hive: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT


Name                           Property                                                                                
----                           --------                                                                                
*                              AlwaysShowExt                         :                                                 
                               ConflictPrompt                        : prop:System.ItemTypeText;System.Size;System.Date
                               Modified;System.DateCreated                                                             
                               ContentViewModeForBrowse              : prop:~System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemTypeText
                               ;~System.LayoutPattern.PlaceHol                                                         
                                                                       der;~System.LayoutPattern.PlaceHolder;System.Dat
                               eModified;System.Size                                                                   
                               ContentViewModeForSearch              : 
[....]
ss                                                         
AcroAccess.AcrobatAccess.1     (default) : AcrobatAccess Class                                                         
acrobat                        URL Protocol :                                                                          
                               (default)    : URL:Acrobat Protocol                                                     
acrobat2018                    URL Protocol :
                               (default)    : URL:Acrobat Protocol
```

I tried to filter it out to just get only custom schemes but with no good result:

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
$REGPATH = "HKCR:\"
Get-ChildItem "$REGPATH" | Where-Object {$_.Property -Match "^(default)    : URL:.*"}
```

Answer (score 0):

at this point i think it is the easiest way:

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
$REGPATH = "HKCR:\"
Get-ChildItem "$REGPATH" >> temp.txt
Select-String -Path .\tmp.txt -Pattern 'URL:'
```